# PHP to convert data from query into json array

Tags: javascript, php

I have some code which queries my database and returns address data. I then convert the address into latitude and longitude in json format so that I can use a javascript function to display markers on a google map. The overall result is an error code regarding an unexpected end to json data. I believe that the problem lies in the php file. When I run it on it's own I get a broken page response. Does anyone see why I might get an error?

Here is the php code:

```
$address = pg_query($conn, "
SELECT 
  incident.address,
  incident.city,
  incident.state_1
FROM 
  fpscdb001_ws_001.incident
WHERE
  incident.initial_symptom = 'Chrome Upgrade' AND
  incident.is_installed != 'true';");

  if (!$address) {
          echo "Query failed\n";
          exit;
        }
$arr = array();
while ($markers = pg_fetch_row($address)){
  $Lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
  $Lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
  $arr[] = array("lat" => $Lat, "lng" => $Lng);
}
echo json_encode($arr);

  }
pg_close($conn);
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if(Array.isArray(arr)){
        showMarkers(arr);
    }
}
}
xhr.open('GET', 'markers.php', true);
xhr.send();

function showMarkers(locations){
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[i % labels.length]
  });
});

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});}}
```

Console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse ()
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (map.php:36)

Comment: Why do you need an array? Just pass a string with the two values.

Comment: What if the error is occurring because your error response isn't in JSON format? I'm referring to where you are echoing `"Query failed\n"`

Comment: Can you console.log() the content of xhr.responseText and paste the result here ?

Comment: I added console.log(arr), but it is not showing anything.

Comment: I think that the error occurs in the JSON.parse() method, so console.log(xhr.responseText) as the first statement of your onreadystatechange would be a better idea. Also, as pointed out by Ananth Rao, you are not returning JSON if your query fails, and you are not handling in your js code

Answer (score 0):

You're delcaring $Lon and using $Lng :

```
  $Lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
  $arr[] = array("lat" => $Lat, "lng" => $Lng);
```

Also, question title is wrong : You want json array, not xml array

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch that. I made the change to the code, but I still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Example code, please test.

markers.php

```
<?php

$p =   [

        ['lat'=>-37.774785, 'lng'=> 145.137978],
        ['lat'=>-37.819616, 'lng'=> 144.968119],
        ['lat'=>-38.330766, 'lng'=> 144.695692],
        ['lat'=>-39.927193, 'lng'=> 175.053218],
        ['lat'=>-41.330162, 'lng'=> 174.865694],
        ['lat'=>-42.734358, 'lng'=> 147.439506],
        ['lat'=>-42.734358, 'lng'=> 147.501315],

      ];

echo json_encode($p);
```

markers.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker Clustering</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

<script>
function initMap() {

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
        });

        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
          });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }

var locations;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if(Array.isArray(arr)){
      locations = arr;
    }
  }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'markers.php', true);
xhr.send();

  </script>
  <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
   <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAkUrEm_U0QWg1QNryI1O5FpB0xAvffJ7I&callback=initMap"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Or two method:

markers.php

```
<?php

$p =   [

        ['lat'=>-37.774785, 'lng'=> 145.137978],
        ['lat'=>-37.819616, 'lng'=> 144.968119],
        ['lat'=>-38.330766, 'lng'=> 144.695692],
        ['lat'=>-39.927193, 'lng'=> 175.053218],
        ['lat'=>-41.330162, 'lng'=> 174.865694],
        ['lat'=>-42.734358, 'lng'=> 147.439506],
        ['lat'=>-42.734358, 'lng'=> 147.501315],

      ];

return json_encode($p);
```

markers_html.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker Clustering</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>


<script>
function initMap() {

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
        });

        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
          });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }

var locations = <?=include("markers.php");?>;

  </script>
  <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
   <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAkUrEm_U0QWg1QNryI1O5FpB0xAvffJ7I&callback=initMap"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```